# Objects are not valid in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

This is my app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
)

import Index from './index'
import Weatherhbh from './weatherhbh'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="widget/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
      <Route path="hbh/" component={Weatherhbh}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

and this  is my hbh component

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const urlP=`/hourly`;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        data:[]
        };
    }
     componentDidMount() {
       axios.get(urlP)
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data,"this is response")
                this.setState({
                 data:response                 
                });
            });
        }


  render() {
    return( <div>

          <p>{this.state.data}</p>

   </div>
   )
  }
}
```

and I get this error

> bundle.js:1244 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a
>   React child (found: object with keys If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of `App`.(…)

how can I fix it so I can display all data which comes from the backend?

Comment: What is the shape of your returned data ?

Comment: what do mean ? if u mean type od fata i send it json

Comment: Yeah so you are setting a json object in your state for data right ? You cannot render an object directly in react, you have to do some processing on it. What information in the data do you want to display ?

Comment: ok i got it , thanks

Comment: i have other issue can i ask u about it?

Comment: if i have other component , how i can pass the data from hbh component  to other component

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState({
    data:response                 
});
```

This section of code here assigns response(an object) to state variable `data` then:

```
  <p>{this.state.data}</p>
```

tries too render the object but react doesn't know how to render objects. To get your data use:

```
<p>{this.state.data.data}</p>
```

since now `data=response` and the axios response has a property called `data` which holds the actual data. And if by any chance the data is also an object(json data), you will have to access the specific key e.g

```
this.state.data.data.username
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error for https://github.com/kushmpatel/auth_React_Demo this demo. Can you please checkout this project and check it? I am learning react native and seriously have no idea where is the problem in my code?